# Get videos from my google photos(public) without logging in and display it in my web page using php?

Tags: javascript, php, google-photos, google-photos-api

I want to build a small video streaming web page using google photos and php/js, I need your help to get all the videos in my google photos to get in json format with video name, playable link etc... and display that in my web page.

What i have tried is google photos api. But i did not find an option like that, If we wanna get details of video list we need refreshToken and to get that I need to allow user to login and then also i can only access his videos.

I want to display my google photo videos in web page without logging in.

Now is there any option like that?

Comment: Would you not just sync your auth token to Google API and display said images on a front-end to the users?

Comment: @Darren, I'm new to google auth tokens. Can you elaborate this pls?.